# VirtualBox Guest:CentOS with KDE, Host:MacOS Sierra Mouse Integration lost (Event Not Responding)

Tags: centos, osx, virtualbox, kde, mouse

I have **VirtualBox 5.1.6** Installed on **Mac OS Sierra**, And I have **CentOS 7 1511** like Guest, and I'm using **KDE** Environment Desktop.

Running the Virtual Machine, the Mouse works perfectly. But Sometimes, later of time working with The Mouse and interacting with it, the mouse is not responding to click Events. But I can see it.

1) **How Can I close CentOS with Keyboard (KDE Environment Desktop)?** (remember my Keyboard for MAC), I want to know the combination of Key /Shortkeys for Gain Access to Menu of Toolbar.

2) **How Can I to Check the Events (where is located log) related to this issue?**

3) **How Can I recover Mouse Integration?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Select Linux Virtual Machine: **CentOS 7 1511**
- Secondary Click -> **Settings**
- Select **System** Tab -> **Motherboard**
- Set Value `USB Tablet` or `USB Multi-Touch Tablet` for **Pointing Device** field!